# my application read the outdated data from the xml file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, telerik, linq-to-xml

I read data from xml file like this :

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
str.Append("<News>");

XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(path);
var q = xmlDoc.Descendants("news")
 .Where(x => x.Descendants("language_id") != null && x.Descendants("language_id").First().Value == "2")
 .Select(x => x);

foreach (var st in q)
{
    str.Append(st.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting) + " ");
}

str.Append("</News>");
return str.ToString();
```

---

but I note recently that when the xml file updated. It still reads the data from the old one !!! I don't know if it reads from a cashing copy or not .

When I reset the `iis` it updates the data .

How to fix this problem?

Comment: what is type of variable path?

Comment: I often found that IIS did not update if I do a simple "build" on my Visual Studio solution. In most cases I really needed a "Rebuild" to make IIS recognize my changes.

Comment: `https://www ...../..../a.xml `

Comment: try using "https://www ...../..../a.xml?DateTime.Now.ToString()" and check

Comment: @just_name Does my answer not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick hack.

Assuming `path` is a string containing a URL, change

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(path);
```

to

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(path + "?" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString(););
```

This will defeat any intermediate caching that's going on, and the use of the `?` in the URL shouldn't upset the server you are asking for data.

(`Guid.NewGuid()` is just a quick way to get a random string. You could easily use the `Random` class or `DateTime.Now.Ticks` in a similar way if you prefer.)

Answer (score 5):

Probably you need setup the DefaultCachePolicy.

```
WebRequest.DefaultCachePolicy = new
RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.Revalidate);
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.Load(myUri);
```

From here: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/stop-xmldocument-load-using-cached-data-t3489418.html

Comment: **Revalidate** `Satisfies a request by using the cached copy of the resource if the timestamp is the same as the timestamp of the resource on the server; otherwise, the resource is downloaded from the server, presented to the caller, and stored in the cache. ` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cache.requestcachelevel%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: how about to disable cache totaly? **WebRequest.DefaultCachePolicy = new System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy(System.Net.Cache.RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);**